# Comando no prompt do CMD Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, prompt

Utilizo o seguinte comando no prompt para descompactar o arquivo e no final fechar a janela. Porém, quando não tem mais arquivos, o mesmo informa que não tem arquivo e não fecha a janela.

Como fazer para ele fechar o cmd mesmo quando não encontre o arquivo?

Código:

```
dir "c:\home\.7z" /s/b > "c:\output.txt" && exit
```

Comment: Considerando que quer um `exit` incondicional, se for usar num script talvez fique melhor colocar o exit numa linha separada, em vez de utilizar operadores (até por uma questão de legibilidade).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Achei. O operador `&&` é executado quando há sucesso. E com `&` ele executa o próximo comando com ou sem sucesso.

Comment: Na verdade, a distinção entre `&&` e `&` é pelo fato do primeiro ser de `curto-circuito`, ou seja, como ele já sabe que vai dar `false` (afinal, deu um erro dizendo que não tem arquivos) ele já retorna o resultado e com isso não executa o próximo comando. No outro caso, ele avalia todos os resultados (no caso, executa todos os comandos).

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos apontamentos e ajustes nos nomes.

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.